# Installing Newtonsoft.Json NuGet Package in .NET 4.0 project fails

Tags: json.net, dependencies, nuget

Why can't I install Newtonsoft.Json in a .NET 4.0 project considering its dependencies?

I have a .NET class library project targetting .NET 4.0 that references the Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.6 NuGet package. I want to upgrade Newtonsoft.Json to the latest version (v10.0.3). This fails with the following message printed out on the Package Manager Console:

> Could not install package 'System.Net.Http 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

The dependency behavior on install was: "Lowest".

Looking at the dependencies of Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package shows:

> **.NETFramework,Version=v4.0**
>   *No dependencies*

Am I misinterpreting something? I expected that it can be installed in a .NET 4.0 project.

The full install log is:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' with respect to project 'XYZ', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3'
Resolved actions to install package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3'
Removed package 'Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.6' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.6' from XYZ Removed package 'System.Net.Http.2.0.20710' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'System.Net.Http.2.0.20710' from XYZ
Adding package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' to folder 'c:\MAIN\packages'
Added package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' to folder 'c:\MAIN\packages'
Added package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' to 'packages.config'
Executing script file 'c:\MAIN\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3\tools\install.ps1'...
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3' to XYZ Install failed.
Rolling back...
Package 'System.Net.Http.4.0.0' does not exist in project 'XYZ'
Removed package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' from 'packages.config'
Adding package 'System.Net.Http.2.0.20710', which only has dependencies, to project 'XYZ'.
Package 'System.Net.Http.2.0.20710' already exists in folder 'c:\MAIN\packages'
Added package 'System.Net.Http.2.0.20710' to 'packages.config'
Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.6' already exists in folder 'c:\MAIN\packages'
Added package 'Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.6' to 'packages.config'
Removing package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' from folder 'c:\MAIN\packages'
Removed package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' from folder 'c:\MAIN\packages'
Could not install package 'System.Net.Http 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
========== Finished ==========
```

The only way to install Newtonsoft.Json into the .NET 4.0 project was to use dependency behavior "Ignore Dependencies".

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Json.NET 10.0.3 has an assembly specifically for .NET 4.0, and has no dependencies if that is the project's target framework, so you should be able to install it into a .NET 4.0 project.

Comment: I'm using VS2015.

Comment: What is the NuGet version?

Comment: NuGet version is 3.4.4.1321.

Comment: Thanks. I have Visual Studio 2015 with NuGet 3.5 and I can install Json.NET 10.0.3 into a class library that targets .NET 4.0 without any errors.

Comment: Upgraded to NuGet 3.5 but have the same issue.

Comment: My .NET 4.0 project depends on Newtonsoft.Json indirectly. It depends on Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 4.0.30506 which depends on Newtonsoft.Json. Maybe this leads to this behavior.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 4.0.30506 looks OK to me. It does not depend on the System.Net.Http NuGet package directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run in Packager manager console

`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 4.0.8`